# Spivak's Calculus Ch. 18, ex 14-15

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have trouble in the following exercise;

"*Find the minimum value of $f(x)= \frac{e^x}{x^n}$, and conclude that $f(x) > \frac{e^n}{x^n}$ for every $x>n$.
Then, prove that $f'(x) = \frac{e^x (x-n)}{x^{n+1}} > \frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$ for $x>n+1$ and thus obtain another proof of $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^n}=\infty$$*

I have got the first two parts (the inequalities) of the exercise correct, but I'm finding difficult to understand how those lead to the conclusion about the limit. The solutions manual suggests that

"*It follows immediately that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$ merely using the fact that $f'(x) > \varepsilon>0$ for some $\varepsilon$ and all sufficiently large $x$*.

What exactly does this mean? Is there a specific theorem (or a deduction of one) related to this claim? And what exactly does this claim suggest?
I 'm not even sure whether I read it correctly. Does it has to be true for any $\varepsilon$, arbitrarily small-large, or is it sufficient to find *one* ("some")?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $f(x)-f(x_0)>(x-x_0)\epsilon$ by MVT.

Comment: Thank you friend, I needed some time to see where to go from here, but with a bit more push I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've proved there exist $c \in \mathbb R$ and $d > 0$ such that
$$ f'(x) > d$$ for all $x > c$.

From this, it follows that
$$ f(x) > f(c) + d(x - c)$$
for all $x > c$.

This is intuitively obvious, since the slope of $f$ is greater than $d$ when $x > c$. For a formal proof, you can use the mean value theorem. Indeed, for any $x > c$, the mean value theorem tells you that there exists a $k \in (c, x)$ such that $f(x) = f(c) + f'(k)(x - c)$. Since $f'(k) > d$, this implies that $f(x) > f(c) + d(x - c)$.

Anyway, having shown that $ f(x) > f(c) + d(x - c)$ for all $x > c$, we can immediately deduce that
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty.$$

Indeed, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( f(c) + d(x - c) \right) = \infty$. Since $ f(x) > f(c) + d(x - c)$, we can conclude that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$ too.

Comment: If I got this straight;

Regarding the function $f(x)= \frac{e^x}{x^n}$, I can choose a point $x_0$ so that $f'(x) > \varepsilon$. In my case, $x_0 = n+1$ (for each $n$, depending on the function) and $\varepsilon = \frac{e^{n+1}}{({n+1})^{n+1}}$

Am I on the right path? The rest are indeed easy to see, it seems that I have yet to understand the importance of MVT.

Comment: Yes, so take $c = n+1$ and $d = \frac{e^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$.

Comment: You 've been realy helpful, friend! Thank you very much!